# Calculate AIC value from a given BIC value?

Tags: aic, bic

Is it valid, given a certain BIC value (an output from an R package) with known *n* and *k*, to transform the BIC value via mathematical manipulation of the formulae for BIC and AIC to get the "equivalent" AIC value?

As a simple numerical example, assume a BIC of -5000 (the value given by the R package) with *n* = 500 and *k* = 20. The *k ln(n)* part of the formula for BIC for these numbers is 124.29. Subtracting 124.29 from -5000 gives -5124.29, which we can assume is the value for the *-2 ln(L)* part of BIC. This *-2 ln(L)* is common to both BIC and AIC, so by substitution we can assume an "equivalent" AIC value of *2k - 2 ln(L)* as 2*20-5124.29 = -5084.3.

Is this a valid equivalence or a completely naive, statistical no-go?

Comment: Can I ask (maybe the obvious), why you did not just derive the `AIC` from your given model with R rather than calculating it from your `BIC` value?

Comment: @Thomas The R package is Ckmeans.1d.dp, a univariate clustering package, which minimises within cluster distances and maximises distances between each cluster mean(s) and sample mean. Because of this joint minimisation/maximisation I am unsure how I should maximise the likelihood myself, and therefore can't calculate my own AIC value. The package only reports a BIC(s) value(s).

Comment: Dear  @babelproofreader, note that in the package you are talking about, they derive and use BIC criterion for Gaussian Mixture Models. "The estimate.k argument specifies the method to select optimal k based on the Gaussian mixture model using the Bayesian information criterion (BIC)."

Answer (score 2):

Two things here. First, the precise definitions:
$$
AIC = 2k - 2\log(\hat{L}),
$$
where $\hat{L}$ is the maximum value of the likelihood function for the model and $k$ is the number of estimated parameters in the model.
$$
BIC = 2k\log(n) - 2\log(\hat{L}),
$$
where $n$ is the size of the sample. Therefore, if you know AIC you can derive BIC and vice-versa.

Second, the implementation. The problem is that AIC and BIC can be implemented differently in different statistical packages. For example, in wikipedia page about AIC it is stated

> **Software unreliability:** Some statistical software will report the value of AIC or the maximum value of the log-likelihood function, but the reported values are not always correct. Typically, any incorrectness is due to a constant in the log-likelihood function being omitted.

Here is the link: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Akaike_information_criterion